# Azure Lucene fuzzy search

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I can't figure out why fuzzy text searching isn't working on an Azure search index.
My search index has a field called Title that is searchable, sortable and retrievable and it has an entry with Title="Hello".

In the search explorer in the azure web portal, a search for an exact match works fine:

```
search=(Title:("Hello"))
```

However, when I add a typo and try to do a fuzzy search, I don't get any matches. What am I doing wrong? I've tried:

```
search=(Title:("Hellp"~))
```

and

```
search=(Title:("Hellp~"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In Azure Search, the simple query syntax excludes the fuzzy/slop options.
```

If you want to use full Lucene syntax you need to specify parameter **queryType** and set a value to `full`

So, for me something worked, when I specified the query via HTTP as following - `search=fieldName:smallp~&queryType=full` and I was able to find documents containing values `small`

More information about Azure Search - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. How can I get it to work while specifying the field? I've tried `search=(Title:"Hellop~")&queryType=full` but didn't get any matches.